# How to compare onle value of a two dimension int array?

Tags: java, arrays, int, compare

I have a two dimensional int array and I want to compare the x value(the one in the first place) of the second position. Like in the code below:

```
COVER = new int[][] {{5, 3}, {10, 9}};
EXAM = new int[][] {{8, 4}, {14, 10}};
```

And I want to compare COVER [1][I don't wanna compare whatever value there is here] with EXAM [1][Just the same as COVER].

Is there a way to do it or I should use a normal int[] array with four positions?

I chose the two dimensional array because the exercise is about a 2D map and I tought this would fit better in the code.

So my real question is how to compare both values, what should I put in the second [], or is there a way to get out the values? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Not able to get you, can you please explain your problem a little more. You want to compare which values ?

Comment: Give also a example of which numbers you want to compare. Based on your `COVER` and `EXAM`

Comment: `COVER[1]` is `{10,9}`. `EXAM[1]` is `{14,10}`. Did you mean you want to compare the 10 and the 14? The 9 and the 10? What are you doing this for? What do the positions represent?

Comment: I want to compare 10 and 14, but imagine that I don't know what their value is

Comment: The positions represent the x and y coords in a map

Comment: So you want to compare `COVER[1][0]` (which happens to be 10) to `EXAM[1][0]` (which happens to be 14)? Well, you just put a comparison operator between them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no work is shown

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong and I understood the problem in right manner then you can follow the following code to solve your problem.

```
public class ArrayComparison {

     public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int COVER[][] = new int[][] {{5, 3}, {10, 9}};
        int EXAM[][] = new int[][] {{8, 4}, {14, 10}};
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                if(COVER[i][j] == EXAM[i][j]) {
                    System.out.println(COVER[i][j]+ " is present at same place in second array.");
                }
                else
          System.out.println(EXAM[i][j]+" is not present at same place in second array.");

            }
        }
     }
}
```

In the above solution I took two loops 'i' for 1st dimension and 'j' for second dimension first the loop will run for i=0 then it will go to 'j' loop and it will run for two times because the there is only two values in 2nd dimension i.e it will run for COVER[0][0] and COVER[0][1] at the same time for EXAM array too and will check the equality that is the value is present at the same position in second array or not , if it is present then it will print that "number is present at same position" otherwise it will print that "number is not present at same position" after that 'i' loop will run for i=1 and after that remaining process will be same as before.
If still you have any doubt the you can ask your doubt again.